# In-place simplification for Coq

Tags: coq

I want this goal:

```
f (S j') = f (j' + 1)
```

to be proven automatically by Coq. Currently I have to write:

```
apply f_equal. omega.
```

But in general it can be more difficult and I might need to assert for instance that m-0 = m and then rewrite. Is there a way to rewrite a term in-place, as Isabelle has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coq has an `autorewrite` tactic which is similar to Isabelle's simplifiers (though in general my impression is that it will not be as high-performance, and Coq users tend to not rely as much on it). Your example could be done like this:

```
Require Import Arith.

Hint Rewrite Nat.add_1_r : myhints.

Theorem blah : forall (f: nat->nat) j',
    f (S j') = f (j' + 1).
Proof.
  intros.
  autorewrite with myhints.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you want.
Perhaps the `replace` tactic can be of help to you.

Basically you would write

```
replace (S j') with (j' + 1).
- (* f (j' + 1) = f (j' + 1) *)
  reflexivity.
- (* j' + 1 = S j' *)
  lia.
```

(Note that I'm using `lia` and not `omega` as `omega` is deprecated in favour of `lia`.)

You can even discharge the replacement directly by `lia`:

```
replace (S j') with (j' + 1) by lia.
reflexivity.
```

This way the replacement only succeeds if `lia` is able to solve the needed equality.

Comment: thanks @ThéoWinterhalter, on the other hand the problem is that I think of more complex cases. I don't want to even say replace "this" by "this other thing" because it would be a lot of work. In Isabelle, you could just apply the simplifier and it will do the work for you. So the question is wether coq can do that

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you expect of the simplifier? You want some process to automatically simplify arithmetic expressions that would know `j' + 1` is _simpler_ as `S j'`?